# Javascript: Simulate cropping and get file image fro memory

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I upload an image using a file input:

```
<input type="file" id="product_images-0"/>
```

Then I get the file with javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('product_images-1');
console.log(element.files[0]);
```

I want to get the image file from memory, show it to user, simulate an image crop to get the coordinates and show the "cropped-simulated" image to the user, by using css transform/translate.

After cropping if the user doesn't like the image can remove it.

It is possible. I don't want to use Ajax because the user can remove an image before submits, and deleting this "remove" image from backend is hard to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see simple proof-of-concept below. Once file is submitted you need to create new `HTMLImageElement` and append it to your preview. Then you can draw cropped image on `canvas` using [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images).

Remember to validate if file you are submitting is image type!

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('product_images-0');
var preview = document.querySelector('div.preview');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

fileInput.onchange = function (event) {
  var curFiles = fileInput.files;
  if (curFiles.length > 0) {
    while (preview.firstChild) {
      preview.removeChild(preview.firstChild);
    }
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[0]);
    preview.appendChild(image);
    image.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0.2 * image.width, 0.2 * image.height, 0.5 * image.width, 0.5 * image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="product_images-0"/>
<div class="preview">
  <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```